Error con icono en C#
Presento errores en C# con referencia al icono de aplicación móvil en MAUI pero ya tengo integrado mi icono en la carpeta correspondiente
adjunto los errores por si alguien los reconoce pueda brindarme información de apoyo

Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error (activo)    APT2067 failed processing manifest.     EntryPay
(net8.0-android)  C:\Program
Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.145\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets 214
Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error (activo)    APT2260 resource mipmap/icon (aka
com.companyname.entrypay:mipmap/icon) not found.
This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml
file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code
file. EntryPay (net8.0-android), EntryPay
(net8.0-android)  C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\EntryPay\APP-MOBILE-EP\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml 1

gracias

De acuerdo al mensaje de error, el problema se indica aquì:

Error (activo) APT2260 resource mipmap/icon (aka
com.companyname.entrypay:mipmap/icon) not found.

Te sugiero revisar el archivo AndroidManifest.xml, debes asegurar de que la referencia al icono sea correcta y coincida con el recurso, revisa que el nombre del icono que se supone se encuentra en la carpeta Resources/Mipmap y que en realidad se llame icon, de acuerdo a lo que indica tu  archivo AndroidManifest.xml
<application android:icon="@mipmap/icon" ... />

